# *.home.gateway timedout - Odd DNS Client Events (Event Viewer) warnings

Tags: windows-7, dns, gateway, event-viewer, billion

I have noticed DNS Client Events warnings in my Event Viewer when my computer is woken from sleep. I have supplied the differing data below and a sample event detail below that.

```
mail.google.com (valid)
wpad.home.gateway (valid)
wwbqyypbrv.home.gateway 
woxdqqronl.home.gateway 
ibadvkibbx.home.gateway 
pxrzmscxdz.home.gateway 
oqmjtajejg.home.gateway
```

`home.gateway` is listed in my router as the `Device Host Name`. My router is a `Billion BiPAC 7300N`.

Apart from it being a warning about accessing those addresses and that some of the names are odd; should I be concerned? thank you.

(I had difficulty determining tags for this. Pls edit if you can improve)

Sample event details below:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client
Date:          27/08/2011 4:40:41 PM
Event ID:      1014
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      
User:          NETWORK SERVICE
Computer:      mikev-ws
Description:
Name resolution for the name lqojbfwsjj.home.gateway timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client" Guid="{1C95126E-7EEA-49A9-A3FE-A378B03DDB4D}" />
    <EventID>1014</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-08-27T06:40:41.904423600Z" />
    <EventRecordID>152907</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="1360" ThreadID="3788" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>mikev-ws</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-20" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="QueryName">lqojbfwsjj.home.gateway</Data>
    <Data Name="AddressLength">16</Data>
    <Data Name="Address">02000035C0A800010000000000000000</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "a wpad".  That lookup results from your WWW browser attempting [WWW proxy auto discovery](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/web-browser-auto-proxy-configuration.html#WPAD) (WPAD).  [That's a serious security hole](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/web-browser-auto-proxy-configuration.html#Security) when one doesn't actually have WPAD locally and you should turn that mechanism in your WWW browser off.

That your system regularly polls a mailbox for new mail is probably a much lesser concern.  ☺

Comment: thanks for that article. so it appears I can't do much for the wpad except to make my own. I was more concerned with the other names listed. sdioughsdpfg.home.gateway. cheers